# Thumb component within Radix's Switch component not transitioning (sliding over)

Tags: tailwind-css, radix

My Radix `Switch` component code using Tailwind works as intended in a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/long-grass-vldbn8?file=%2Findex.jsx%3A8%2C62). But within my own local environment the `Thumb` component does not transition (the slider part). It stays stationary.

In the gif below (taken from Storybook) you can see properties getting updated on click (the slider background goes from black [checked state] to red [unchecked state]). I also tested this out outside of Storybook and the results are the same.

The code is identical in both environments.

The only difference I can possibly think of are the packages? In the sandbox everything is listed as `latest`. Here's what I have locally...

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@radix-ui/colors": "^0.1.8",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0"",
    "@radix-ui/react-switch": "^1.0.2",
    "classnames": "2.2.6",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "1.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.1",
    "vite": "^4.3.5"
  },
```

[image]

Comment: So I went ahead and made all my [sandbox packages be the same as local](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/radix-switch-lower-react-version-tjmzi8?file=%2FApp.jsx%3A35%2C1) but that didn't seem to brick the `Switch` component. This makes me think the sandbox global css package is different from what I have.

Answer (score 0):

Okay after figuring out it wasn't any of the packages and thinking it was my css, I saw within `index.css` that `@tailwind base;` was commented out (we are using some legacy MUI components). After enabling this line of code the `Switch` worked!

[image]

[image]